# How to get Resharper to use Visual Studio's snippets

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

I installed Resharper in VS2008 and it seems to have taken over some of the snippets I've come to rely on. For instance, prop, foreach, etc...

How can I tell Resharper to let VS2008 use its own snippets or at least not to overwrite snippets that already exist.
Better yet, is there a way to selectively tell Resharper which snippets it can overwrite and which it shouldn't?

I know about the Live Templates menu item that lets you pick and choose, but after deselecting 'foreach', for example, VS (or probably Resharper) treats it as a function.
In other words, when I type 'fore' and hit tab for autocomplete, I end up with 'foreach()' instead of the snippet operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can uncheck the ones that you don't want to use from Live Templates window. foreach template is under iterations group.

Comment: I did that, but then it treats it as a function, e.g. auto-complete results in its use as a function.  See the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: Well, I have read it and I tried the way you described. It was working correct at first and now I am trying again and surprisingly I am facing the same problem!

Comment: It seems like a bug to me because it works fine before ReSharper's IntelliSense is loaded, but after it is loaded (by pressing Ctrl+Space) it behaves like the way you described. Good luck with that.

Comment: Please let us know if you find an answer!

Comment: go to the menu `ReSharper` > `Tools` > `Templates Explorer` and then uncheck the ones you don't want. May you required to go to a specific `scope` or language.

Comment: @AngryHacker Wow, I have to type the snippet name such as `foreach`, press `Esc` and then press `Tab`. I use `Esc` to avoid the parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

I know I am late to the party but you can use snippet editor to copy your snippet then paste it into Resharper through the live template editor. The code appears to be compatible. I did that with several of mine and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since ReSharper 4 Visual Studio code snippets are imported into ReSharper as live templates. That means you can invoke any code snippet by pressing Ctrl+J.

All the scripts imported in Vs are available on this popup menu.

Comment: no one is arguing that. The issue is that edited VS snippets are being overwritten by ReSharper

Answer (score 1):

Resharper is great in some respects, but in others it can be unbelievably frustrating when it just rides roughshod over years of muscle memory.

Options => Environment => IntelliSense => Completion Behavior => [Uncheck] "Replace Keywords with Live Templates"

Comment: But don't hit tab twice.  Thanks Resharper - because that will still treat it as a function and just add some parens.  'cause, you know.