# IntelliSense has forgotten my code snippets!

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, code-snippets

I have a stack of code snippets imported into Visual Studio. Just recently, they have stopped displaying in Intellisense.

If the keyboard shortcut doesn't bring up anything else on IntelliSense, then I can tab and the code snippet is inserted just fine.

However, if the keyboard shortcut for the snippet happens to also bring up other items in IntelliSense, tabbing will select the first of those items, so I actually can't use the code snippet at all!

Does anyone have any ideas why IntelliSense would be unable to list my code snippet shortcuts? I started using ReSharper recently, but that wouldn't be the problem surely?!

Thanks for your help

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly connected to installing Resharper.  First thing it does is turn IntelliSense off.  Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473956/how-to-get-resharper-to-use-visual-studios-snippets) for help with preserving your snippets.

Comment: Okay - so it is a ReSharper issue.

Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to the party but you can use snippet editor to copy your snippet then paste it into Resharper through the live template editor. The code appears to be compatible. I did that with several of mine and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at this but ReSharper's live template UI seems mostly incomprehensible. I definitely can't find a way to simply import the .snippet file. I'll keep looking at it.

Comment: copy and paste. Copy the snippet code from the integrated snippet designer(available from the extension manager. Then paste it into the editor for Live Template.

Answer (score 0):

Since ReSharper 4 Visual Studio code snippets are imported into ReSharper as live templates. That means you can invoke any code snippet by pressing Ctrl+J.

All the scripts imported in Vs are available on this popup menu.